# making checkboxes inside div responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one responsive container div

I want to have six checkboxes with text in this div, which I need to make responsive as well. Problem I am facing is when I reduce screen size checkboxes coming outside of div and making screen unresponsive. How can In fix this?

I want to have checkboxes as shown in below image

[image: checkboxes]

```css
css : .rectangle {
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 2vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>
```

Comment: Can you put your markup for the problem you're actually having?

Comment: For small screens do yu want the checkboxes to be in 1 line or can it goes to the next line?

Comment: I made you a snippet and spelled radius correctly. Please add more HTML in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `@media` query to fix the problem:

```
@media screen and {max-width: 'number'} {
     .rectangle {
          overflow: none;
      }
}
```

Comment: If any questions, Tag me.